# mail() in php not working for edu emails

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send email using Php function mail(). IT sends email to gmail accounts but it is not sending to .edu accounts. Can anyone tell me the reason why and help me to solve the same? below is my code and my php version is 5.5.26

```
<?php
$email = "abc@gmail.com";
$url = "http://example.com/Scripts/ActivateUserAccount.php?email=".$email;




$emailFlag = mail($email, "Cmpln Account Verification", "Hello Welcome to Cmpln.". phpversion());
if($emailFlag)
{
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "email sent";        
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "email not sent"; 
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: The mail server for the particular university might be filtering your emails - also try to check spam folder.

Comment: If the code successfully sends email at all, it works. The fact that specific address don't appear to receive it isn't because of your code.

Comment: if php mail returns `true`, then it's not (directly) a php problem. You need to check your mailserver's logs to see what happened when it tried to actually deliver the mail. php's job is the equivalent of walking your envelope down to the street corner and tossing it into the mailbox. once that mailbox door shuts, php is done and reports true. if the mailbox is later nuked out of existence, that's not php's problem.

Answer (score 0):

The university or the email client is blocking them, probably as part of a spam filter.

Try whitelisting the email address in your client and try again. If this does not work, then the block is being done at the server level and short of having the university whitelist the sending domain there wont be much you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can change to avoid your PHP mail() script looking spammy, as that may be sending it to a junk folder or the account may be automatically blocking it as it thinks it may be spam. Take a look at this article:

http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/

and try something along these lines:

```
$headers ="From:<$from>\n";
$headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso 8859-1";

mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f$from");
```

Headers do a lot more than some may think!